# How to save in a file bash and psql history?

Tags: bash, psql

I need help for the question on topic : i'm new to centos 6 environment and i need to export in a file the 2 histories so i can send it through e-mail.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default `bash` typed commands are saved in `~/.bash_history` and `psql` saves it in `~/.psql_history`, so you could send those files with this command:

```
$  mail -s 'My history files' -a ~/.bash_history -a ~/.psql_history  myemail@gmail.com
```

Note that not all `mail` commands support the -a flag to send attachments, heirloom-mailx in ubuntu does.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but i've got another problem : when i try to access the file .bash_history,i've got a Permission Denied error.What can it be the cause?

Comment: are you the owner of the file?, otherwise you must be root.

Comment: Already tried,with the command ~/.bash_history the yum installer start and try to install postgres/postgis and other packages...i did something wrong i suppose?

Comment: I dont follow you, sorry. You are asking about where is the history,  and it is in those files normally. If you have problems with your OS might be you can open more specific questions.